# Table Size in ADX

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to get list of all tables size in Azure Data explorer(ADX).

Do we have any single query or table having all tables size meta data ?

I can able to see data using below query:

```
.show table dev_adls_la_parsed extents;
let tbl_size = $command_results
| summarize num=sum(ExtentSize) by DatabaseName, TableName| extend SizeinGB = format_bytes(num, 2)
| project DatabaseName, TableName, SizeinGB;

tbl_size
| project DatabaseName, TableName, SizeinGB;
```

Output:

[image]

Using below Query trying to store data in one table for better visibility.

```
.create table adx_tables_space(databaseName:string, tableName:string, SizeinGB:string)
```

```
.show table dev_adls_la_parsed extents;
let tbl_size = $command_results
| summarize num=sum(ExtentSize) by DatabaseName, TableName| extend SizeinGB = format_bytes(num, 2)
| project DatabaseName, TableName, SizeinGB;

.set-or-append adx_tables_space <|
tbl_size
| project DatabaseName, TableName, SizeinGB;
```

It throwing some error:

```
Syntax Error 

 A recognition error occurred. 
 Token: . 

 Line: 12, Position: 0

 clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.show database extents**

---

**!!** This command is undocumented and might be changed/deprecated in the future.

---

```
.show database extents 
| summarize Extents             = count()
           ,RowCount            = sum(RowCount)
           ,OriginalSize        = format_bytes(sum(OriginalSize), 2)
           ,ExtentSize          = format_bytes(sum(ExtentSize), 2)
           ,CompressedSize      = format_bytes(sum(CompressedSize), 2)
           ,IndexSize           = format_bytes(sum(IndexSize), 2)
            by TableName
| order by  RowCount
```

| TableName | Extents | RowCount | OriginalSize | ExtentSize | CompressedSize | IndexSize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trips | 100 | 1547471776 | 475.79 GB | 100.3 GB | 78.95 GB | 21.35 GB |
| FHV_Trips | 34 | 514304551 | 37.91 GB | 5.92 GB | 5.78 GB | 146.13 MB |
| nyc_taxi | 11 | 165114361 | 25.29 GB | 7.43 GB | 7.34 GB | 95.35 MB |
| GeoRegions | 1 | 5139969 | 250.35 MB | 18.79 MB | 12.94 MB | 5.85 MB |
| demo_many_series1 | 1 | 2177472 | 153.7 MB | 12.21 MB | 9.01 MB | 3.21 MB |

...

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22RsQ6CMBCGdxPe4UZIiIO7E3Fw0UTdzdWeSkJb0ysBjA%20vjQIF2/Hv93%209XJd8Nw1IdCiQCah1pB1DsngB10qhLZ8Em18anjVcTK1dmiWLIM0Ppil8PkU/qrS/mRX2tryVGqujf2goXI1V6M6ic8Spb4dYlsNqZvlOGDqilhGLOAqjHpaYSY6eiGOKRTxbLamdjhLzDNi/AkQHJxQV7VCR/wpjJVmfQr/FN4eMWNG4AQAA)